# Why Eslint plugin for import order doesn't work in CRA?

Tags: javascript, create-react-app, eslint

I installed `eslint-plugin-import-order` and add it to `eslintConfig` in `package.json`.

Error I have:

```sh
Definition for rule 'import/order' was not found (import/order)
```

Please, help me to deal with it.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-elbakyan-pilnc

Answer (score 15):

**Note:** `eslint-plugin-import-order` has been deprecated. Please use this
https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import

create a `.eslintrc.json` file and add the plugin like below.

```
{
  ....,
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:import/errors", "plugin:import/warnings"],

  "plugins": ["import"],
  
  .....
}
```

Restart your local server once to ensure the changes are reflected.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, but without success. My codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-elbakyan-pilnc

Comment: @bigbabyweb Seems weird that this doesn't work in codesandbox but works perfectly in my vscode editor.